# INNER JOIN Query with Objection JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, objection.js

I got the following data model: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1T5i.jpg

Basically, A `User` can belong to many `Projects`, and a `Project` can have many `Users` and I'm tying that together through a join table called `UserProjects`

With a raw SQL query I can go

```sql
SELECT "user".email, project.name FROM "user"
JOIN userprojects ON userprojects.user_id = "user".id
JOIN project ON project.id = userprojects.project_id
```

Which gives me

```
email(On User table)               name(On Project table)
first@email.com                    Project X
first@email.com                    Project Y
second@email                       Project Y
```

How would I structure this query with Objection ORM? Perhaps I can just do a raw query straight? Something like

```
User.query().raw(SELECT "user".email, project.name FROM "user"
JOIN userprojects ON userprojects.user_id = "user".id
JOIN project ON project.id = userprojects.project_id)
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nvm, found a solution

/close

JK,

Here's what worked for me if anyone else would run into the same issue:

```
return User.query().where("user_id", parent.id)
.join('userprojects', 'user.id', '=', 'userprojects.user_id')
.join('project', 'project.id', '=', 'userprojects.project_id')
.select('user.id', 'userprojects.project_id', 'project.name')
```

Comment: still working in objection 3.0.x and knex 2.1.x.  Thank you

Answer (score 14):

instead of doing all the stuff by yourself, Objection.js can do it for you. You can just declare a `ManyToManyRelation`.

```js
      static relationMappings = {
        projects: {
          relation: Model.ManyToManyRelation,
          modelClass: Project, // imported Objection class of "Project"
          join: {
            from: 'user.id',
            through: {
              from: 'userprojects.user_id',
              to: 'userprojects.project_id'
            },
            to: 'project.id'
          }
        }
      }
```

Then you can just get the projects of a User using eager loading:

```js
    User.query().eager('projects').findById(userId)
```

And you will get something like:

```js
    User {
      id: 3,
      firstname: 'firstname',
      lastname: 'lastname',
      email: 'email',
      projects: [
        {id: 1,
        name: 'name1'},
        {id: 2,
        name: 'name2'},
      ]
    }
```

---

**2020 Update:**

Since version 2 of `Objection.js`, `eager` method has been renamed as [`withGraphFetched`](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/guide/query-examples.html#eager-loading):

```js
    User.query().withGraphFetched('projects').findById(userId)
```

Comment: Interesting approach, didn't know you could do that type of inner joins with Objection.

I'm using GraphQL for the queries though, so that messes things up, but thanks for the tip. Good to know

Comment: Objection.js has interesting Graph features. I would recommend you to check them http://vincit.github.io/objection.js/#graph-inserts :)

Comment: Wow, Objection JS never fails to amaze me - what a terrific ORM

Comment: Thanks for the excellent example.  I couldn't figure out why I kept getting "unknown relation".  It turned out that I have to name my relations in the Model.  +1!